# The Bevel tool has suddenly begun making stars rather than normal bevels, how can I change it back?

Tags: bevel

**Final edit:** I have learned much more about the bevel tool since last time of writing, and have come to realize that the behavior I previously regarded as "normal" is in fact not normally supposed to occur, but I found a way to recreate it. By selecting both corners and edges at the same time, and beveling them, it pre-cuts the edge bevels with no line in the middle. I have removed a couple redundant images to add two more on the bottom: the pre-cut bevels that have no edge in the middle. This is what was occurring by default for me on EVERY edge bevel I made, and I have come to realize that this is in fact not how it's supposed to work. Additionally, as I find having that center edge more useful to interact with, I'll just stick to adding it in later regardless. Sorry for all the confusion, hope this clears things up. Other than the strange bug of course.

Original text (reference numbers for images changed to match new images):

I was following a fairly simple tutorial, and beveling random edges and corners on an object, when suddenly the bevel tool began making a star shape rather than the previous behavior of making a cut through an edge, or flattening a corner. This is occurring on multiple areas of the same object, and even on other objects. I'm not sure if there's some button I accidentally pushed that caused this change, but it seemed to occur after saving the project. Is there any way to change how the bevel tool applies to faces? You can see the intended bevel in the screenshots below, as well as the star-shaped bevels that are being created now.

Scrolling only changes the amount of vertices in the star shape, making it progressively rounder. I just tried restarting Blender, the issue persists. Making a new object and beveling that object also yields the same results. This also occurs in new projects. I am using CTRL+B, then pressing V to create the bevels, and this has previously worked on all other bevels I've made, giving the result you see in the non-star-shaped bevels. I am running Blender 4.0.2, on Windows 10, latest version as of time of writing.

In the first two images, you can see the rounded/star shaped bevels being created, and in the third and fourth images you can see the expected behavior of the Bevel tool on corners and edges respectively. In the fifth image, you can see the bevel tool attempting to bevel both corners on an edge, despite edge mode being selected. You can see below that this behavior is new and it was not originally doing this, instead beveling the entire corner.

[image]

[image: Bevel tool creating a star shape on Edge Bevel mode.]

[image: Bevel tool creating a star shape on Vertex Bevel mode.]

[image: Correct Bevel behavior on corners.]

[image: Correct Bevel behavior on edges.]

[image: Bevel tool not behaving correctly on edges.]

[image: Pre-cut bevel.]

[image: Pre-cut bevel closeup.]

Comment: check the option in the Operator Box (bottom left of your 3D view), also make sure that you don't have overlapping vertices (select all and press M > Merge by Distance), inner faces, inverted normals (press Shift N to recalculate)... Or please share your file

Comment: I am not sure what option you're referring to, I do not have overlapping vertices (confirmed by dragging the vertex around), I have recalculated normals, and I have added my file to the original post. However, I have also discovered that this also occurs in brand new projects.

Comment: for example, for the last picture you show, it seems normal, what kind of result were you expecting?

Comment: I have once again edited my post to include images of the expected behavior of the bevel tool. It should simply cut out a flat surface between each of the selected points. On a simple cube, it should cut out a triangle shape between each edge of the cube, on the corner.

Comment: Your file is working as expected for me, make sure to have 1 segment, if you have more than one, you get a star shape bevel

Comment: I have edited my post yet again, as apparently this is affecting entire edges as well as corners. I have one segment selected, but this is still not the behavior it was using before. This is entirely new to me, and this bevel function is not how it was behaving before. You can see other bevels in my work throughout the screenshots, how it was working before. Every corner that isn't straight has been made with a simple bevel (CTRL+B, V), which is no longer doing what it was before.